# Identify unauthenticated Cognito Identity ID from request

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have an AWS API, with access controlled by an [IAM authoriser](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-authentication-api-gateway/) associated with the unauthenticated role of a Cognito Identity pool. A successful call to the API invokes a Lambda function.

The current process is:

1. User obtains [temporary security credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html). This includes:

   - User `IdentityId` e.g. `eu-west-2:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`. **This is the information I require in my Lambda function - see below.**
   - Access credentials: `AccessKeyId`, `SecretKey` and `SessionToken`
2. The user calls the API using [a signed request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/create-signed-request.html). The header of the request includes `X-Amz-Security-Token`, obtained from step 1
3. If authorisation is successful, the request is sent on to the Lambda function. `event.headers` includes `X-Amz-Security-Token`

Is it possible for the Lambda function to identify the identity pool ID of the caller (e.g. `eu-west-2:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`), either from the data available in the header of the request, or any other means.

Things I have tried:

- [sts.getCallerIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/get-caller-identity.html) with `Invoke with caller credentials` ticked in API Gateway
- Looking at `SessionToken`, though this appears only to be a temporary access token rather than containing any useful data like a JWT.

If absolutely necessary I can include the identity ID of the user with every request, but I'd prefer to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Cognito ID of the user is included in the `requestContext` property of the `event` object passed to your Lambda function.

E.g. the Identity of the Cognito user that access the API is:

```
event['requestContext']['identity']['cognitoIdentityId'];
```